# How to get Php Intellisense with Monaco Editor?

Tags: reactjs, electron

Im trying to make my own editor based on monaco like vscode, but with better intellisense for php. Right now it only suggests words that I already created. How do i do that? I think I need to spawn a php server, but how would I implement that? Im using Electron and React.